# Convert Date in PHP to XMLGregorianCalendar format and back

Tags: php, datetime, gregorian-calendar

I'm calling a SOAP web service that expects to receive a date/time in XMLGregorianCalendar format.  So, for example, I would need to convert YYYY-MM-DD HH:MM:SS to that format.

When I retrieve data from the web service, I would need to convert date/time from XMLGregorianCalendar format to YYYY-MM-DD HH:MM:SS.

I would normally post some code that I have tried but, in all honesty, I'm having trouble locating anything to even get me started with PHP.  So my apologies for the lack of sample code.  Would REALLY appreciate any guidance.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The date format used in XML is ISO-8601. You can use strftime to convert it to a Unix timestamp and date to convert it back to a nice readably sting.

These format string might come handy:

- "Y-m-d H:i:s" sample: "2014-06-27 20:14:49"
- "c" sample: "2014-06-27T20:14:49+00:00"

You can check supported time formats of strtotime here:
http://de3.php.net/manual/en/function.strtotime.php

And syntax for date here: 
http://www.php.net/manual/en/function.date.php

```
$date = date("Y-m-d H:i:s", strtotime($date)); // Output as datetime used in SQL 
$date = date("c", strtotime($date)); // Output as datetime used in XML
```

Comment: Thanks.  This is the date/time format they're expecting:  `2014-07-26T10:29:26.163-06:00`  I understand what everything is except the T and the .163.  Assuming the T just denoted the start of the time.  Not sure what .163 is?

Comment: That is the normal iso-8601 time format. St r to time can perfectly parse this and date ("c") will output it again. Check the doc on date.

Comment: Ah makes sense - really appreciate it.